# When to use semicolon

Tags: syntactic-analysis, semicolons

I have gone through lots of posts on the internet, but couldn't find any convincing answer for the correct usage of the semicolon in sentences.

Also, I'd like to know why we can't use a full stop everywhere instead of a semicolon, or vice versa.

Comment: The super-comma usage is discussed [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/138136/strange-sentence-structure-from-a-piece-by-paula-gunn-allen/138141#138141), and the semicolon vs comma (between independent clauses) question  [here](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233348/is-it-ok-to-combine-two-independent-clauses-into-just-one-sentence/233604#233604).

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is like between a full stop and comma, it would be weird to put a full stop since it would be too short but too long to put it a comma.

Answer (score 0):

**1.for seprating independent clauses which are not joined by coordinating conjunctions** (remember the acronym "FANBOYS" to recall the most important coordinating conjunctions : for , and , nor , but , or , yet , so.)

**2.for separating Items in a series that contain comma.**

Example : I visited London , England ; Prague , Oklahoma

**3.when your sentence contains sentence connectors , like : nevertheless , therefore , thus , etc.**

*note : when you have sentence connectors , there are 4 ways to use punctuations*

1. She did not study well ; therefore , she didn't pass the test
2. She did not study well . therefore , she didn't pass the test
3. She did not study well . she , therefore , didn't pass the test
4. She didn't study well . she didn't pass the test ,therefore.

Comment: Hi! I thought I'd tell you that the space goes *after* the punctuation mark, not before and after, as it seems you are doing here. The first letter of any word is capitalised at the start of a sentence, too.

Comment: @Mari-LouA oh I am sorry it seems I did not read your comment carefully last time .really sorry :) I won't repeat it . thanks :)

Comment: [Related](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/598864/2085).